# Substituting New Relic query element with Bash variable - Bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, substitution, newrelic

I would like to query New Relic (a logging/monitoring service) for some metrics using the New Relic API. I am running this query through a Docker container using a Bash script, and attempting to pass in a dynamic variable.

Here is my simplified script:

```
##!/bin/bash

day='Since 1 day ago'

#GPU Metrics Query
newrelic nrql query --accountId {account_id} --query 'SELECT * FROM NvidiaGpuMetricSample $day'
```

The query that the New Relic API accepts is:

```
newrelic nrql query --accountId {account_id} --query 'SELECT * FROM NvidiaGpuMetricSample Since 1 day ago'
```

And the error message I receive with this Bash script above is:

```
level=fatal msg="NRQL Syntax Error: Error at line 1 position 37, unexpected '$'"
```

I have tried to use different methods to pass in the variable, for example using `'eval $day'` and passing that in a new variable or using `/"$day"/` within the query string, but nothing seems to give the API what it is looking for.

Summary: I would like to pass a string variable into a string query using Bash.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

`newrelic nrql query --accountId {account_id} --query "SELECT * FROM NvidiaGpuMetricSample $day"`

Referencing variables in Bash is possible only inside double quotes, see https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately the New Relic query only accepts single quotes for the `--query` argument.

Comment: @OmarShah How is this possible? It is a concern of Bash how to declare string literals. `newrelic` executable should not even know if you have used single or double quotes. Does it show any error with double quotes?